# Menu doesn`t open if you go over too fast

Tags: css

The menu I made is working fine if you go over items very slowly if you go a bit faster than it dissappear. How can I fix it ?

Video; http://screencast.com/t/5GvIa1jYHzk
Link to my site; http://tinyurl.com/3g58vhb

Comment: 1 - what does the video link have to do with anything? 2- is this browsers specific? I used chrome and the menu seems fine? 3 - post the code for the menu so we can take a look.

Comment: It wigs out in Firefox. It appears to have something to do with a javascript hover/mouseover issue. Firebug shows it constantly switching back and forth between `display:none` and `display:block`. Posting the javascript code running that nav would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that the  is slightly too far down from the . If you change this line in the css:

```
nav ul ul {       
    top: 27px;
}
```

Developer tools say this is in common.css, around line 888.

You should be able to get rid of this issue. In chrome I set it to `top: 26 px` and that worked but I would test it in the other browsers as well.

I realized that you might still have an issue with moving the mouse to fast. You can solve this using setTimeout function so that when somebody scrolls over the  three second later it will hide the . Then if the mouse enters the  cancel the setTimeout.